# Group dictionary by values and return list of keys

Tags: vb.net, excel, linq, dictionary

The following code is intended to inspect the values of Excel cells and return a `List(Of Excel.Range)` containing only those cells whose values are unique.  The line with the question marks is the one causing the pain.

```
  Private Function UniqueValues(ws As Excel.Worksheet) As List(Of Excel.Range)
    Dim listRanges As New List(Of Excel.Range)
    Dim dicValues As New Dictionary(Of Excel.Range, Object)

    For Each rng As Excel.Range In ws.UsedRange
      dicValues.Add(rng, rng.Value2)
    Next

    'Get list of cells with unique values
    listRanges = dicValues.Keys.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Value2).ToList '????

    dicValues = Nothing
    Return listRanges
  End Function
```

What is the correct code for the line with question marks?  Please respond in VB.NET, as I have a hard time converting LINQ from C# to VB.NET given the dearth of VB.NET LINQ examples on the Internet.

Comment: I removed the C# tag, since it is unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 0):

That should do the Trick:

```
listRanges = dicValues.Values.Distinct().ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks, but Visual Studio doesn't like that and says that "'DistinctBy' is not a member of...'"

Comment: add the `Imports System.Linq` to the class

Comment: What is `DistinctBy()` - is this from an imported library?

Comment: Adding Imports System.Linq didn't help, and neither of the proposed solutions worked.  Does it matter that I am using .NET 4.0 Client Profile?

Comment: @MacG Whoops there was a 2 too much: Values2 -> Values. Tried it out now with:         
`Dim list As New List(Of String)
 
Dim dicValues As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

dicValues.Add("test", "test2")

dicValues.Add("test2", "test2")

dicValues.Add("test3", "test4")

list = dicValues.Values.Distinct().ToList`

For me its now just showing test2 and test4. And not test2, 2 times.

Comment: The edited solution above just returns List(Of Object), not List(Of Excel.Range).  It probably worked for you because your key and value are the same type (String).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ultimately ended up doing, which worked.  I believe there is probably a faster way using LINQ that does not require the second loop, so if someone has a more elegant solution, please post it.

```
  Private Function UniqueValues(ws As Excel.Worksheet) As List(Of Excel.Range)
    Dim listRanges As New List(Of Excel.Range)
    Dim dicValues As New Dictionary(Of Excel.Range, Object)

    For Each rng As Excel.Range In ws.UsedRange
      dicValues.Add(rng, rng.Value2)
    Next

    'Get list of cells with unique values
    Dim uniqueVals = dicValues.Where(Function(x)
                                       Return dicValues.Where(Function(y) y.Value = x.Value).Count = 1
                                     End Function)
    For Each itm In uniqueVals
      listRanges.Add(itm.Key)
    Next

    uniqueVals = Nothing
    dicValues = Nothing
    Return listRanges
  End Function
```